# PCL - error C2039: 'PointType' : is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<T>'

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to implement some code from the pcl [NARF tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/narf_keypoint_extraction.php)

But this code:

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::RangeImage> range_image_ptr (new pcl::RangeImage); 
pcl::RangeImage& range_image = *range_image_ptr;   
range_image.createFromPointCloud (point_cloud, angular_resolution, pcl::deg2rad (360.0f), pcl::deg2rad (180.0f), scene_sensor_pose, coordinate_frame,oise_level, min_range, border_size);
```

always results in the following errors:

> error C2039: 'PointType' : is not a member of
> 'boost::shared_ptr'    C:\CLibraries\PCL
> 1.5.1\include\pcl-1.5\pcl\range_image\impl\range_image.hpp    193
>
> error C2039: 'points' : is not a member of
> 'boost::shared_ptr'    C:\CLibraries\PCL
> 1.5.1\include\pcl-1.5\pcl\range_image\impl\range_image.hpp    194

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing this problem in the future: The error shows up for the wrong file. It says there is an error in `range_image.h`
The actual problem is that I didn't use a pointer to the pointcloud.

```
rangeImage.createFromPointCloud(pointCloud, angularResolution,...
```

It should be this:

```
rangeImage.createFromPointCloud(*pointCloud, angularResolution,...
```